# How to escape double quotes in shopify product metafield value?

Tags: api, rest, shopify

I'm using curl in a php script to send an api request to shopify as described at https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/metafield?api%5Bversion%5D=2020-01#create-2020-10.  Specifically I'm sending the following to https://[user]:[pwd]@[store handle].myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-10/products/[product id]/metafields.json:

```
Array
(
    [metafield] => Array
        (
            [namespace] => specs
            [key] => Length
            [value] => 2\"
            [value_type] => string
        )

)
```

And I get the error 422 Unprocessable Entity back from shopify.  I also get the same error without the backslash before the double quote.  If I replace the quote with the word inches it is added without any error.  Is there a proper way to escape double quotes within metafield values in shopify?